# Using <animate> on SVG viewBox itself only works twice

Tags: xml, animation, svg, smil

I've been trying to use 2 different s on SVG viewBox to cycle between sizes, but though both animations work independently, the second one won't run if the first begins again after it. What's strange to me is that the first one will keep running, indicating that it 'recognizes' the end of the other animation, even though it doesn't show. If I remove the 'small.end' it even will run both the way they're supposed to....but that means they won't repeat one after the other.

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 300 300">
    <animate id = "big" attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "0;small.end" dur = "0.96s" from = "0 0 300 300" to = "0 0 650 390" fill = "freeze" />
    <animate id = "small" attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "big.end" dur = "0.96s" from = "0 0 650 390" to = "0 0 300 300" fill = "freeze" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yXDZ2/

I've been looking at various things like the coordinate system, additive and accumulative animation, etc., but can't seem to get a grasp on why this is behaving this way. I suspect it might be an issue of 'resetting' the animation state somehow but I'm getting a little out of my depth - i don't mind using javascript or any libraries to achieve that.  Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if you still care, but your fiddle above works (i.e. repeats) fine in Chrome 42.

Comment: @mrec interesting....thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Mullany's suggestion is definitely an easier way to do this, but it's worth a little more detailed examination:

First thing to mention is that the problem only happens in Webkit/Blink browsers; in Firefox, you get the bouncing animation as expected.

What seems to be happening in Chrome (and other webkit browsers) is that it is letting the "freeze" value of the first animation over-ride any change made by the second animation.  If you get rid of the freeze attribute on the first animation, then the second animation's freeze value blocks the first animation from displaying.

This is *not* how it's supposed to work, the default behaviour for two animations affecting the same property is that later animations should have a higher priority than earlier ones.  Specifically, the SMIL specs say:

> [Higher priority animations that are not additive will override all earlier (lower priority) animations, and simply set the attribute value.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#AdditiveAnim)

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the `additive` attribute (or, at least, the option of specifying `additive="sum"`) only applies to certain types of animated properties: lengths, colours, and vectors.  It *doesn't* apply to a complex attribute like "viewBox".  The webkit browsers therefore seem to be *ignoring* the default `additive="replace"` behaviour.

To demonstrate, if we add in an animation that *could* potentially be additive, like a change in colour, *then* the two animations correctly replace each other despite the "freeze" setting:

http://jsfiddle.net/yXDZ2/2/

That alone, however, doesn't explain why your second animation works fine *if* the first animation isn't set to restart after the second animation ends.  My guess is that has something to do with an error in the way webkit calculates "priority" of multiple animations.  For multiple animations that *start at the same time*, the priority is determined by looking at whether one's start time is dependent on the other.  However, that calculation shouldn't affect animations that started at different times -- for that case, the later animation should always take priority.

Either way, **I would call this a bug in the webkit implementation.  I couldn't find any relevant bug reports on the webkit Bugzilla, you might want to do a more thorough search and file an issue if you can't find one.**

---

As to how to deal with the problem in the meantime:

As suggested, you could combine both animations into one multi-value animation.  This is probably the simplest approach and cleans up your code.

Since you're not actually "freezing" the value at either end, another way to do what you want would be just to remove the `fill="freeze"` parameter from both:

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 300 300">
    <animate id = "big" attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "0;small.end" 
             dur = "0.96s" from = "0 0 300 300" to = "0 0 650 390" />
    <animate id = "small" attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "big.end" 
             dur = "0.96s" from = "0 0 650 390" to = "0 0 300 300"  />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yXDZ2/1/

However, that wouldn't work if you wanted to run the animation, freeze it, and then wait a specified time before beginning the reverse animation.  To get that to work you'd need to either

- define it as a single animation with multiple values, some of which are repeated twice to "freeze" that value, and specified keytimes for each step; *or*,
- define `set` animation elements that start after each of the transition animations completes and hold the specified value for a set time without freezing it indefinitely.

Comment: this is beyond helpful - it's downright educational. thanks so much, ameliaBR!

Comment: Glad you found it useful.  I spent enough time trying to figure out why it *wasn't* working that I felt I should write it up.  At least there are fairly easy work-around options for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single animate element with a values array.

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 300 300">
    <animate attributeName = "viewBox" dur="1.92s" values="0 0 300 300; 0 0 650 390;0 0 300 300" fill="freeze"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: wow, thanks so much! is there a way to delay or choose when to move between values in the array? i made this example up, but my actual project features animations that run on beginElement() calls, so if i could just use one animation tag with an array like yours to go back and forth, that would be amazing....

Comment: @Ettubrutesbro: To set the time used for each transition in a `values` array, specify a [`keyTimes` array](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#KeyTimesAttribute).  To "hold" a value, you'll need to list it *twice* in the `values` array, and then specify a time for how long it should take to "transition" to itself.